# What is the rate limit of the Esplora instance blockstream.info

Tags: api, blockstream

Blockstream.info provides a free API, for example: https://blockstream.info/testnet/api/tx/d4b1add055db58343500157a6525a73ceb9c8850f0fb435f1f60071e8cad6540

I would like to know what the rate limit for this Esplora instance is?

Comment: Does this refer to https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora ?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes, but I'm asking about Blockstream's service which might use different rate limiting than the default?